# How to add title to total_segments section of javascript totals object In Magento 2

Tags: magento, magento2

I have setup a custom total "oversized_shipping_fee" however I am not able to set the title in the js totals object for some reason as seen below:

my code is as follows:
class OversizedShippingFee extends AbstractTotal
{

```
/**
 * @var Client
 */
private $client;

/**
 * OversizedShippingFee constructor.
 * @param Client $client
 */
public function __construct(Client $client)
{
    $this->_code ='oversized_shipping_fee';
    $this->client = $client;
    $this->_getTotal()->se
}

/**
 * @param Quote $quote
 * @param ShippingAssignmentInterface $shippingAssignment
 * @param Total $total
 * @return $this|AbstractTotal
 */
public function collect(Quote $quote, ShippingAssignmentInterface $shippingAssignment, Total $total)
{
    /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address $address */
    $address = $shippingAssignment->getShipping()->getAddress();
    if ($address->getAddressType() === \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address::ADDRESS_TYPE_SHIPPING) {
        $feeObject = $this->getFee($quote);
        $fee = $feeObject->getData('price') ?: 0.0;
        $total->setTotalAmount($this->getCode(), $fee);
        $total->setBaseTotalAmount($this->getCode(), $fee);
        $quote->setData('oversized_shipping_fee', $fee);
        $quote->setData('oversized_shipping_fee_code', $feeObject->getData('code'));
        $quote->setData('oversized_shipping_fee_title', 'test');
    }
    return $this;
}

/**
 * @param Quote $quote
 * @param Total $total
 * @return array
 */
public function fetch(Quote $quote, Total $total)
{
    $fee = $this->getFee($quote)->getData('price');
    $sku = $this->getFee($quote)->getData('description');


    $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/total_segment.log');
    $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
    $logger->addWriter($writer);
    $logger->info($sku);

    return  [
        'code' => $this->getCode(),
        'value' => $fee,
        'title' => 'test'
    ] ;


}

/**
 * @param Quote $quote
 * @return DataObject
 */
private function getFee(Quote $quote): DataObject
{
    $request = $this->client->createRequest();
    $request->initRequest($quote);
    try {
        return $this->client->send($request)->getOversizedShippingFee();
    } catch (ApiException $ignore) {
        return new DataObject();
    }
}
```

}

the value of title attribute is null here, and I am not sure how to change it or how to add a new key-value pair such as "sku": "SKU-vale"

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Firstly verify `sales.xml` that you have define proper total in the quote section quote and add fees

```xml
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Sales:etc/sales.xsd">
    <section name="quote">
        <group name="totals">
            <item name="fees" instance="VL\Checkout\Total\Quote\OversizedShippingFee" sort_order="150"/>
        </group>
    </section>
    <section name="order_invoice">
        <group name="totals">
            <item name="fees" instance="VL\Checkout\Total\Invoice\OversizedShippingFee" sort_order="150"/>
        </group>
    </section>
    <section name="order_creditmemo">
        <group name="totals">
            <item name="fees" instance="VL\Checkout\Total\Creditmemo\OversizedShippingFee" sort_order="150"/>
        </group>
    </section>
</config>
```

Also, make sure to load module after checkout for that add sequence in the `module.xml` and then run setup upgrade to update the module dependency.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="VL_Checkout" setup_version="1.0.0" schema_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Sales"/>
            <module name="Magento_Quote"/>
            <module name="Magento_Checkout"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

please add the `getLabel()` method in the `OversizedShippingFee` file

```php
<?php

namespace VL\Checkout\Total\Quote;

use Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface;
use Magento\Quote\Api\Data\ShippingAssignmentInterface;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total\AbstractTotal;
use VL\Checkout\Helper\Data;
use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context;


class OversizedShippingFee extends AbstractTotal
{

    /**
     * @var PriceCurrencyInterface
     */
    protected $_priceCurrency;
    protected $_helper;
    /**
     * @param PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency
     */
    public function __construct(
        PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency,
        Data $helper,
        Context $context
    ) {
        $this->_priceCurrency = $priceCurrency;
        $this->_helper = $helper;
        $this->scopeConfig = $context->getScopeConfig();
    }

    /**
     * @param Quote $quote
     * @param ShippingAssignmentInterface $shippingAssignment
     * @param Total $total
     *
     * @return $this|bool
     */
    public function collect(
        Quote $quote,
        ShippingAssignmentInterface $shippingAssignment,
        Total $total
    ) {

        parent::collect($quote, $shippingAssignment, $total);
        $address = $shippingAssignment->getShipping()->getAddress();
        if ($address->getAddressType() === \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address::ADDRESS_TYPE_SHIPPING) {
            $baseFees = $this->getFee($quote);
            $fee = $this->_priceCurrency->convert($fee);
            $total->addTotalAmount($this->getCode(), $fee);
            $total->addBaseTotalAmount($this->getCode(), $baseFees);
            $total->setBaseGrandTotal($total->getBaseGrandTotal() + $baseFees);
        }
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param Quote $quote
     * @param Total $total
     * @return array
     */
    public function fetch(Quote $quote, Total $total)
    {
        $amount = $total->getFee();
        if ($amount == 0) {
            $amount = $quote->getFee();
        }
        $title = $this->getLabel();
        return [
            'code' => $this->getCode(),
            'title' => $title,
            'value' => $amount
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get label
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Phrase
     */
    public function getLabel()
    {
        return __('test');
    }
}
```

in the js file you can console.log the `totals.getSegment('fees')`

and display the text in html

`fees.html`

```html
<!-- ko -->

  <tr class="totals fee excl">
        <th class="mark" scope="row">
            <span class="label" data-bind="text: title"></span>
            <span class="value" data-bind="text: getValue()"></span>
        </th>
        <td class="amount">

            <span class="price"
                  data-bind="text: getValue(), attr: {'data-th': title}"></span>


        </td>
    </tr>   

<!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: this worked once I created the getlabel function and set the title key to the value of getlabel()  ..... using title => ' anything else'   does not work.  Thanks a lot Viral Langhanoja

Comment: I'm trying to access the title value like this totals.getSegment('oversized_shipping_fee').title in my js, is this the correct way to do it ?

Comment: You should require to create a getLabel method due to the override the value of the `AbstractTotal` class and regarding the use of title you can use any binding to reflect that value. You can use the data-bind="text: getTitle()" with the following function also

Comment: ```js
getTitle: function () {
            let title = null
            if (this.totals() && totals.getSegment('oversized_shipping_fee').title) {
                title = totals.getSegment("oversized_shipping_fee").title;
            }
            return title;
        },
```

if you want want to statically declare the title in the `checkout_index_index.xml` you can also define the `<item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Static Title</item>` in your config array of your charges component and use it with data-bind="text: title" show in the above comment.

Comment: Viral Langhanoja , hope you can help me with this question also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63257679/how-to-add-notes-to-magento-2-email-totals-section